# MySQL: Add to Count with case... then

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case

I have a sql query which is working perfectly to return the number of hours a worker is working in any particular job

```
SELECT worker.WorkerID, worker.fullname, job.JobCode, job.jobName, Count(slottime.FK_Hour) AS NUMBER_OF_HOURS_WORKED 
FROM (
        (
            (job INNER JOIN slot 
            ON job.JobCode = slot.fk_JobCode
            )
            INNER JOIN (worker INNER JOIN slotworker ON worker.WorkerID = slotworker.FK_worker) 
            ON slot.SlotNo = slotworker.FK_SlotNo) 
            INNER JOIN slottime ON slot.SlotNo = slottime.FK_SlotNo
        ) 
LEFT JOIN manager ON (job.JobCode = manager.FK_JobCode) AND (worker.WorkerID = manager.FK_WorkerID) GROUP BY worker.WorkerID, worker.fullname,  job.JobCode, job.jobName, manager.is_the_boss
```

However, not all workers are equal. Workers who are allocated as managers are paid an additional 2 hours per job.

the manager table is structured as **JobCode**, **WorkerID**, **is_the_boss**

**is_the_boss** simply records '1' in the event that that worker is allocated the manager position of that particular job.

How would I affect the count of slottime.FK_Hour such that an additional 2 hours are added for each of the jobs where (CASE WHEN is_the_boss = 1) is true?

Comment: Side note, Shouldn't you use `SUM` instead of `Count` to get total hours for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below

```
SELECT worker.WorkerID, worker.fullname, job.JobCode, job.jobName, Case When manager.is_the_boss = 1 Then Count(slottime.FK_Hour) + 2 Else Count(slottime.FK_hour End  AS NUMBER_OF_HOURS_WORKED 
FROM (
    (
        (job INNER JOIN slot 
        ON job.JobCode = slot.fk_JobCode
        )
        INNER JOIN (worker INNER JOIN slotworker ON worker.WorkerID = slotworker.FK_worker) 
        ON slot.SlotNo = slotworker.FK_SlotNo) 
        INNER JOIN slottime ON slot.SlotNo = slottime.FK_SlotNo
    ) 
LEFT JOIN manager ON (job.JobCode = manager.FK_JobCode) AND (worker.WorkerID = manager.FK_WorkerID) GROUP BY worker.WorkerID, worker.fullname,  job.JobCode, job.jobName, manager.is_the_bos
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is rather hard to follow.  Why have all those parentheses in the `from` clause (unless you are using MS Access and you have no choice)?  It is simpler to just list the tables with the `join` criteria.

Solving your problem requires counting the number of job codes where the worker is the boss.  You can do this with a conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT w.WorkerID, w.fullname, j.JobCode, j.jobName,
       Count(st.FK_Hour) AS NUMBER_OF_HOURS_WORKED,
       count(distinct case when m.is_the_boss then j.jobCode end) * 2 as ManagerHoursWorks
FROM job j INNER JOIN
     slot s
     ON j.JobCode = s.fk_JobCode INNER JOIN
     slotworker sw
     ON slot.SlotNo = sw.FK_SlotNo INNER JOIN
     worker w 
     ON w.WorkerID = sw.FK_worker INNER JOIN
     slottime st
     ON s.SlotNo = st.FK_SlotNo LEFT JOIN
     manager m
     ON j.JobCode = m.FK_JobCode AND w.WorkerID = m.FK_WorkerID
GROUP BY w.WorkerID, w.fullname,  j.JobCode, j.jobName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
SELECT worker.WorkerID, worker.fullname, job.JobCode, job.jobName,  Case When manager.is_the_boss = 1 Then Count(slottime.FK_Hour) + 2 Else Count(slottime.FK_hour End  AS NUMBER_OF_HOURS_WORKED
FROM job 
INNER JOIN slot  ON job.JobCode = slot.fk_JobCode
INNER JOIN slotworker ON slot.SlotNo = slotworker.FK_SlotNo
INNER JOIN worker ON worker.WorkerID = slotworker.FK_worker
INNER JOIN slottime ON slot.SlotNo = slottime.FK_SlotNo
LEFT JOIN manager ON (job.JobCode = manager.FK_JobCode) AND (worker.WorkerID = manager.FK_WorkerID)
 GROUP BY worker.WorkerID, worker.fullname,  job.JobCode, job.jobName, manager.is_the_boss
```